# Where can I find all detailed explanations for vim color theme items?

Tags: vim

I made a semi_diy vim color theme online months ago.

But I find it not sufficient enough. So I tried manually fix it today.

But the problem is:

**I can't find detailed explanations for these items online**

Googled, went to vim.org, nothing.

Anyone knows where can I find detailed explanation for items such like(there are much more!) :

```
FoldColumn
PreProc
EnumerationName
Visual
MoreMsg
SpellCap
VertSplit
Exception
Keyword
Type
DiffChange
Cursor
SpellLocal
Error
PMenu
SpecialKey
Constant
DefinedName
Tag
String
PMenuThumb
MatchParen
LocalVariable
Repeat
```

Some of them are clear, but some are obscure.

For example, I have no idea what's the name of the function which examines if a bracket has a correspond another half bracket.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kent's answer gets at the root of your confusion. However, to directly answer your question:

The meaning of all of these highlight group identifiers can be found by opening vim and reading `:h highlight-groups` (which just jumps into `syntax.txt`, the file Kent mentions).

Comment: Not exactly, part of these items are in :h syntax, such as String.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, I have no idea what's the name of the function which
>   examines if a bracket has a correspond another half bracket.

I think you are confused by **highlight-group** and **syntax**

The things you've listed are not "functions" they are hi-groups. They decide **How** the color-highlighting should be applied. E.g. foreground red, background yellow, bold font etc. They don't decide **when** the groups should be used. It was done by `syntax`.

You can define for example, string starts with `#` and ends with `@@` apply hi-group `Exception`.

Then the corresponding part in `this is #foo bar blah@@ something else` would be highlighted using hi-group "Exception"

For writing syntax file, you have to read `:h syntax` for details.